# Query returning individuals most recent order, date of the order, number of products in the order and the total amount

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help with a query to returns each individuals most recent order, date of the order, number of products in the order and the total amount. I am kind of stuck trying to get the number of products and total.

Here are the table diagrams

Not sure if I should be using multiple joins or subqueries:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, MAX(O.OrderDate), O.OrderDate
FROM Customer C 
    INNER JOIN Order O ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is better if you post details as text instead of pictures. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Also please provide a few rows of sample data and an expected result

Comment: By "number of products in the order" do you mean "number of different products" or do you mean, the number of OrderItems in the order?

Comment: the number of different products in the order

Comment: Please add list of columns names you are expecting to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always good practice to start from assumed dim tables such as `product`.This Query should help. It is better to aggregate quantity and amount to get results at aggregate level

```
SELECT FirstName
    ,LastName
    ,max(o.orderdate) Orderdate
    ,Sum(Quantity) Quantity
    ,Sum(TotalAmount) TotalAmount
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN Orderitem oi
    ON Oi.product_id = p.id
INNER JOIN
ORDER o
    ON o.id = oi.order_id
INNER JOIN Customer c
    ON c.id = o.Customer_id
GROUP BY FirstName
    ,LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you want aggregations but here you go:

```
SELECT customer.firstname, customer.lastname, COUNT(DISTINCT orderitem.productid), [order].totalamount 
FROM [order] LEFT JOIN customer ON [order].customerid=customer.id LEFT JOIN orderitem ON order.id=orderitem.orderid 
WHERE [order].date=MAX([order].date)
GROUP BY customer.firstname,customer.lastname, [order].totalamount
```

Still don't know why you are applying a where clause for the last order, it's up to you to keep or not the where condtion.

Comment: How do u know max id has max date on it, It is only an assumption. This doesn't work

Comment: That's why I wrote i didn't know why He wanted the max order... It's up to him to decide if he wants to keep it or change the clause.